# Using the definition of limit, prove the limit (n to infinity):

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Using the definition of a limit prove that:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+2\cdot10^n}{5+3\cdot10^n} = \frac{2}{3}$$

The definition in my textbook is $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L $: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $ M > 0$ so that if $x \in S$ and $x > M$ then $\vert f(x) - L \vert < \epsilon$

The bit I'm struggling with is finding an inequality between M and epsilon. I understand that the Archimedean property is needed for this, but I can't quite figure it out, and graphing the function didn't seem to help me out. Other questions I've found on this problem took this for granted.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: hint: show $|f(n)-\frac 23|<\frac 73\times\frac 1{5+3.10^n}<\frac 79.10^{-n}<10^{-n}<\frac 1n$

Comment: Remember the informal meaning of that definition: If you make $x$ get really huge, then you can make $|f(x) - L|$ get as small as you want. You should never be directly comparing $M$ and $\epsilon$, because $M$ should be large and $\epsilon$ should be small.